# SQL Server in Shiny

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, shiny-server

When I upload this code to the web Shiny can't load it. When I enter Shiny it tells me the following error:

> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 00000: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source  [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unexpected EOF from the server  [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  is_local = Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == ""

  server = "server"
  database = "base"
  uid = "login"
  pwd = "pwd"

  dbConnector <- function(server, database, uid, pwd, 
                          local=TRUE, port=1433, tds_version=8.0, 
                          Encrypt=yes, TrustServerCertificate=no){
    if(local){
      DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                     driver   = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                     server   = server, 
                     database = database, 
                     uid      = uid, 
                     pwd      = pwd
      )

    }else{
      DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                     driver      = "FreeTDS",
                     server      = server,
                     database    = database,
                     uid         = uid,
                     pwd         = pwd,
                     port        = port,
                     tds_version = tds_version
      )
    }
  }

  conn <- dbConnector(server, database, uid, pwd, is_local)

  #Criando as tabelas dentro do servidor
  df <- dbGetQuery(conn, 'SELECT * FROM TABLE')
  )
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The odds are that this is a firewall issue. All firewalls between the webserver and the SQL Server must have the appropriate port(s) open to communicate between the two machines. It could also possibly be a permissions issue based on internal network security vs external connections.

Comment: FYI I tried to edit your code with more consistent indentation, but it looks like you have a spare `)` or a missing `}` somewhere